# How to add html after a certain div using Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I want to be able to append divs to my page such that they are appended after a div of a certain class and before teh divs that follow it i.e:

```
<div class="header">Header DIV</div>
<!-- Want to add using javascript some HTML right here-->
<div class="one-basic-div">...</div>
<div class="one-basic-div">...</div>
<div class="one-basic-div">...</div>
<div class="one-basic-div">...</div>
```

It is basically raw html I wish to add. How can I do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`Element.insert`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/insert/) method:

```js
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $$(".header").first().insert({ after: "<p>Some html</p>" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js"></script>

<div class="header">Header div</div>
<div class="one-basic-div">Other div</div>
```

Comment: any motive for the lack of ";" on the first line, or presence on the second?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`insert`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert):

```
$$('#header').insert({ 'after' : theHTML });
```

That should insert it as a sibling after the div with id `header`.

There are some helpful examples [here](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/the-stupidly-brief/), the documentation seems to be lacking, somewhat.

Comment: I think you'll have to add a `[0]`.